# scipy butterworth filter has no delay? What's the trick?

Tags: python, scipy, butterworth

**On the following graph:**

- **Orange**: original signal
- **Blue** : butterworth filter from scipy applied.
- **Grey** : a custom implementation of butterworth filter applied.

[image]
**On the following graph:**

- **Orange**: same original signal
- **Blue**: another custom implementation of butterworth filter applied.

[image]

**Question:**

Both custom implementations have delay while scipy's does not have. What's the trick?

Note: Custom implementations don't give the same result because they don't have the same coeff.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We don't know the parameters of the filter, the sample rate, the number of samples, exactly which SciPy function you used, etc.

Comment: Having said that: if you pass the coefficients of a Butterworth filter to `scipy.signal.lfilter`, there will be a delay.  Are you using `lfilter`, or one of the other filter functions?

Comment: I'm confused by your first graph. It has no blue and grey lines. It does have purple and brown lines, however. Could you clarify which one is which?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, sorry for the lack of information. Based on your second comment, I went to documentation. I'm using filtfilt function and I suspect that the answer is in this sentence: "This function applies a linear digital filter twice, once forward and once backwards". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using filtfilt function.

Based on Warren Weckesser comment, I went to documentation and it states that

> This function applies a linear digital filter twice, once forward and
> once backwards. The combined filter has zero phase and a filter order
> twice that of the original.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html